# JetEntityFrameworkProvider setup in VS2017

Tags: jet-ef-provider

After compiling my project in `VS2017 15.9.21` for.NET 4.5, I got following error, what am I missing?

```
Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'JetEntityFrameworkProvider.JetProviderFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.
```

[Error Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9ZhM.png)

This is where the exception gets thrown:

```
JetConnection.ShowSqlStatements = True

Dim fac1 = New JetConnectionFactory()
Dim con1 = fac1.CreateConnection(ORMGlobal.ConnectionString)

Using db As ORM = New ORM(con1)
    Dim model = db.People.Count()
    ' ...
End Using
```

This is my DbContext setup:

```
Partial Public Class ORM
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        Database.SetInitializer(New NullDatabaseInitializer(Of ORM))
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(con As Common.DbConnection)
        MyBase.New(con, True)
        Database.SetInitializer(New NullDatabaseInitializer(Of ORM))
    End Sub

    ' ...
End Class
```

This is my `config.app`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="JetEntityFrameworkProvider" type="JetEntityFrameworkProvider.JetProviderServices, JetEntityFrameworkProvider" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="JetEntityFrameworkProvider"/>
      <add invariant="JetEntityFrameworkProvider" name="Jet Entity Framework Provider" description="Jet Entity Framework Provider"
        type="JetEntityFrameworkProvider.JetProviderFactory, JetEntityFrameworkProvider"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Exception details:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in EntityFramework.dll
5/20/2021 3:49:07 PM :dwl: :LV:: Error in ConnectToDSN: System.NotSupportedException: Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'JetEntityFrameworkProvider.JetProviderFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderFactoryExtensions.GetProviderInvariantName(DbProviderFactory factory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultInvariantNameResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<GetService>b__0(Tuple`2 k)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.RootDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CompositeResolver`2.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbDependencyResolverExtensions.GetService[T](IDbDependencyResolver resolver, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInvariantName(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.get_ProviderName()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ProviderName()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DefaultModelCacheKeyFactory.Create(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at TheBoardRoom.LockView.SQLdbHandler.ConnectToDSN(String sConnDSN, ADOConnection& connDB)
```

Comment: I think that Factory requires GAC registration. Try to connect using JetConnection directly.

Comment: Which factory? I just added both ```JetEntityFrameworkProvider ``` and ```EntityFramework``` to GAC, then rebuilt. Same result, error persist.

Comment: Instead using `(New JetConnectionFactory()).CreateConnection(ORMGlobal.ConnectionString)` try to use `New JetConnection(ORMGlobal.ConnectionString)`.

Comment: I did just that. But, this doesn't fix anything. Got the same exception. I think somehow ```JetEntityFrameworkProvider``` is not properly registered in ```config.app```. For reference, I am using latest ```EF6.4.4```. Did you make this ```JetEntityFrameworkProvider``` work in VS2017 VB.NET project?